# Algorithm to automatically adjust resource pool capacity based on demand

Tags: algorithm, pool

You are the producer of a resource which takes a while to create (let's say a couple minutes for illustration). You have consumers requesting instances of that resource, and the pattern of requests is not initially known (and can vary over time).

Using a resource pool is an obvious choice. But what is a good and simple way of choosing and evolving the pool capacity over time in a way that:

- **Reduces wait time**: we want most consumers get their request fulfilled with no wait at all (let's say 90% of the time).
- **Minimizes waste**: assume that keeping these resources in the pool is expensive, so we don't want a large number of them sitting around for extended time.

I'm not looking for some advanced AI learning solution here, but for a simple algorithm that adjusts the pool size based on simple factors, e.g.

- resources currently left in the pool
- age of the resources in the pool
- frequency of requests

Clearly, there are more than one way to do this, and the optimal algorithm will depend on how expensive resources are, how bad it is to make consumers wait, and the kind of organic request pattern you are getting (e.g. slowly ramping up vs bursts). But I'm looking for a solution that does a decent job under most situations, and has a few constants that can be tweaked based on real world problem.

To illustrate, I'll give a fairly naive example algorithm:

- Start with a pool size of 10
- If pool to 20% of total capacity (so initially 2 items), increase pool size by one.
- If oldest item in pool (i.e. the one next in line to be used) is older than 1 hour, decrease pool size by 1.

Comment: The only way to solve this problem is with a few year's experience. You're going to have daily usage patterns (nighttime vs daytime), weekly usage patterns (weekends vs weekdays), and yearly usage patterns (holidays and/or seasons). So you need to invest in excess capacity until you have enough experience to optimize production. As an architect on the Azure team, you already know that, so I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: @user3386109 assume for the sake of this question there are no calendar based patterns (even though you're right that in many real world scenarios there would be some). Instead, the focus is on adapting capacity based on organic demand as it comes.

Comment: As I see it, you would need to assume some model for the access patterns and update it as new data comes. This should fit nicely with with something like Bayesian on-line parameter estimation, if you can swallow that pill (e.g. Poisson distribution with Gamma prior).

Comment: @jdehesa I'm looking for something more straightforward. I added an example in the question to illustrate.

Comment: The next level up from the naive example is a [PID controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller).

Comment: @user3386109 interesting, will read up on that.